# Set path to JDK for SonarQube in ant

Tags: java, ant, java-8, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have been setting up an ant script to run SonarQube analysis following instructions in https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Ant

My issue is, that compiling and building process is done with Java 7u45. JAVA_HOME is set to corresponding JDK.

SonarQube requires JDK8 to make analysis. I have copied JDK 8 to that server, but how can I specify path to it in ant for SQ to use, if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set your JAVA_HOME to a JDK 8, and within your ant script adjust the `source` and `target` attributes of the `javac task` for Java 7 if you need to compile for Java 7, something like :

```
<javac srcdir="${src}"
  destdir="${build}"
  fork="true"
  source="1.7"
  target="1.7"
/>
```

See [ant manual javac task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) for all the details.

**-EDIT-**
If setting JAVA_HOME is no option, you may start your ant process via batch file, setting JAVA_HOME and all other settings, f.e. :

```
set ANT_HOME=C:\ant197
set ANT_ARGS=-lib C:\antxtralibs
set JAVA_HOME=C:\jdk180_121
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin;%PATH%

:: default
ant -f %1

:: debug
:: ant -debug -f %1
```

**-EDIT-**
For Jenkins use https://yourjenkinshost/configure/Tools and create an additonal JDK 8 with JAVA_HOME set to the root of this JDK Folder/Installation.
Then configure your specific job to use that JDK 8, while other jobs will use your default JDK.

Comment: We have it already in our scripts. But setting JAVA_HOME to JDK8 is unfortunately not an option in our case. Thanks for advise though.

Comment: @Romczyk OK, so starting with batchfile or shellscript on Linux maybe an option, see edit !?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned, that we run all builds on Jenkins. We have around 30, which run many times a day and only in one of them I needed this change to JDK 8 to run SonarQube analysis.

Comment: @Romczyk OK, so why install a JDK 8 on Jenkins and configure this specific job to use JDK 8, other jobs will use your default JDK ?

Comment: I do not install JDK8, I only copy folder with it there. Other builds are using this slave too and this special job is running only once at night. SonarQube requires JDK8 to run

Comment: @Romczyk Of course you don't need an installer, just use https://jenkinshost/configure/Tools and configure an additonal JDK 8 with JAVA_HOME set to the copied Java folder.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It really solved my issue. Problem was well in another place.

Comment: @Romczyk Just saw my typo : "OK, so why install a JDK 8 on Jenkins .." Should have been = OK, so why NOT install a JDK 8 on Jenkins ..